# If linearity follows from homogeneity and additivity why do non-homogenous systems of linear equations exist?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity) wikipedia page, Linear Maps or Linear Functions satisfy properties of homogeneity and additivity. *(Later on in the paragraph they also talk about how this can be extended for linear operators like derivative or differential)*

At the same time, the definition of **non-homogenous** **linear** ODE (of first order) is: 
$y\ '$ + $p(x)y$ = $r(x)$ where $r(x)$ $\neq$ $0$

Why is there a mismatch in the definition of Linearity?

Comment: Why do non-homogeneous systems of linear equations exist?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.